# Redirect to Login View from Controller In Code-igniter Error occured

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Hi I'm new to php and code igniter. what I tried is to get login info from view and validated user and need to send a message to user whether login details are incorrect.

Controller Code :

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('login_model');
    $this->load->helper('form'); 
    $this->load->helper('url');

    }
    public function index()
    {
        //$this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('login/login');
    }
    public function login_check()
    {
        //$this->load->view('hello');
        //echo "directed";
    $user_id = $this->input->post('usernm');
    $userPassword = $this->input->post('passwordd'); 
    //echo $user_id.' and'.$userPassword;
    $var = $this->login_model->check_login($user_id);
    $status = 0;
    if(empty($var))
    {
        echo "Invalid user";
        $status = 0;
    }
    else
    {
    //echo var_dump($var);
    $username = $var->username;
    //echo $username;
        $status = 1;

    }
  $this->load->helper('url');
  redirect('login/login');
  //$this->load_>view('login\login');// at this point it does not redirect to login page and instead of that displaying error 404.page not found.
//echo $status;

    }
```

}

Same url ,earlier loaded when it called from from index function but  fi it is calling from login check()function  does not directed to the view and displaying error 404 page not found.

Any assistance regarding this world be a great help.
Thanks a Lot!

Comment: it can't be redirected because you don't have a controller name login. what you are trying to redirect is your page view login/lgoin. use redirect(''); instead it will redirect to your Welcome/index controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write **redirect('welcome');** instead of **redirect('login/login');**. Because *login/login* is the view page and you are trying to redirect direct on view without using controller. So you have two option which I had written bellow.

1. redirect('welcome');
2. $this->load->view('login/login');

My suggestion is please choose 1st option because 2nd option already you have implemented in first one.

Comment: Thanks a lot redirect ('welcome') was worked perfectly. Thank yo u very much for the assistance !!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one will work on you.

```
    public function login_check()
    {
       $user_id = $this->input->post('usernm');
       $userPassword = $this->input->post('passwordd'); 
       $var = $this->login_model->check_login($user_id, $userPassword); //pass username and password to your model to authenticate if input exists.
       $data['error'] = '';
    if(!empty($var)) //check if var is not empty
    {
        $this->session->set_userdata($var); //set user_data to var
        redirect('Account/page');  //redirect it to your account or success page
    }else{
         $data['error'] = 'Invalid Username or Password.';
         }
        $this->load->view('login/login',$data); //pass the error notification to your page.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! @session Start .This works perfectly and your extra explanation was really helpful.again thank you very much for the support!!! :)

Comment: Welcome @Heshan.